# Why is moment.js not formatting the date from an API in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am getting some information from the API, and there's a problem with data form change with Moment.js

```
d=>console.log(`Venue ${d.data[0].venue.name}, location ${d.data[0].venue.city}-${d.data[0].venue.country}, date ${require('moment').moment(d.data[0].datetime,'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss').format('MM/DD/YYYY')}`)
```

I'm getting this error...

```
TypeError: require(...).moment is not a function
at process.argv.(anonymous function).concert-this.process.argv.(anonymous function).require.get.then.d (C:\Users\19513\Desktop\Homework\LIRI\liri.js:20:142)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Please post more code showing how you are requiring moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('moment')` already returns a reference to moment. You don't need to call from that returning value to a function named `moment`; it is already a function.

```
let moment = require('moment');
moment(d.data[0].datetime,'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

although is barely readable, if you want to inline it, it would be

```
require('moment')(d.data[0].datetime,'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

although I do not recommend it to do it like that

See [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/)